# Function on php file

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I have this code that I got from here

```
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
```

I want to know how to put it in my index php file because it's not working, know that I'm working on a joomla template and the class quote is on one of the modules. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `in my php file`? You mean in your html content? Maybe provide more details about your setup ...

Comment: If this is js code add it between <script></script> tag.

Comment: I put that script in the index file .php, and yes between script tags but it doesn't work, my setup is joomla template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();